# Proving that ($Z$, $⊗$) is a semi-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

This is a solution to an Abstract Algebra question but I don't understand the steps to the solution. It looks like some steps were jumped. I understand that $(Z,⊗)$ must be associative in order to be a semi-group. So in the first equation, $(xy + c(x + y + c^2 - c)$ is multiplied by z to give $xyz + cxz + cyz + c^2z - cz$ but then I don't get where the rest of the equation came from.

[image: solution]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/de1291a5cc07e3149649218a15b7089c.png?1365631945))</sub>

Same goes for the second equation.

Can someone please explain how the long equation came about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression is not multiplied in the usual sense, but `multiplied' using the operation $\otimes$ defined above. Furthermore, the text proves $(\mathbb{Z},\otimes)$ to be a semigroup rather than $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know how to do the ⊗ sign. What's the difference?

Comment: If it's not multiplied then what is it doing?

Comment: It's defined in the text: $x\otimes y = xy+c(x+y)+c^2-c$.

Comment: Okay, but how does that affect the proving with $Z$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ here is just understood to be the **set** of integers, and $(\mathbb{Z},\otimes)$ is the set of integers equipped with the binary operation $\otimes$ as defined above. The claim, which is proven, is that $(\mathbb{Z},\otimes)$ is a semigroup.

Comment: I don't know if that answers your question, but I don't really see what you mean by `the proving with Z'.

Comment: OK. I'll but it this way, how was this equation derived. $xyz + cxz + cyz + c^2z - cz + cxy + c^2x + c^2y+ c^3 - c2 + cz + c^2 - c$

Comment: By calculating $(xy+c(x+y)+c^2-c)\otimes z$... Should we move this discussion to chat maybe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8286/discussion-between-adegoke-a-and-abel)